# How to kubectl wait for crd creation?

Tags: kubernetes, azure-devops, wait, kubectl, kubernetes-custom-resources

What is the best method for checking to see if a custom resource definition exists before running a script, using only `kubectl` command line?

We have a yaml file that contains definitions for a NATS cluster `ServiceAccount`, `Role`, `ClusterRoleBinding` and `Deployment`. The image used in the `Deployment` creates the `crd`, and the second script uses that `crd` to deploy a set of `pods`. At the moment our CI pipeline needs to run the second script a few times, only completing successfully once the `crd` has been fully created. I've tried to use `kubectl wait` but cannot figure out what condition to use that applies to the completion of a `crd`.

Below is my most recent, albeit completely wrong, attempt, however this illustrates the general sequence we'd like.

`kubectl wait --for=condition=complete kubectl apply -f 1.nats-cluster-operator.yaml kubectl apply -f 2.nats-cluster.yaml`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The condition for a CRD would be `established`:

```
kubectl -n <namespace-here> wait --for condition=established --timeout=60s crd/<crd-name-here>
```

You may want to adjust `--timeout` appropriately.

Comment: I find that I still get `Error from server (NotFound): customresourcedefinitions.apiextensions.k8s.io "environments.fission.io" not found
` with this command occasionally, so I think waiting for just the `established` condition is insufficient. Anyone aware of a better way of doing this that is resilient to races with the CRD's creation?

Comment: @hornairs -- have you been able to determine why the CRD wasn't created? if it fails only (quote) "...occasionally" - is it possible that the `--timeout` argument needs to be increased?

Comment: This fails for me `kubectl wait --for condition=established  --timeout=60s crd/servicemonitors.monitoring.coreos.com` with
`Error from server (NotFound): customresourcedefinitions.apiextensions.k8s.io "servicemonitors.monitoring.coreos.com" not found`

Comment: `while ! kubectl wait --for condition=established --timeout=60s crd/<crd-name-here> ; do`
`sleep 1`
`done`

should cover also `error: unable to recognize ... no matches for kind ... in version ...` error

Comment: Why would I use wait here if it just throws error if the resource is not there?

Comment: The above `-n <namespace-here>` is useless because CRDs are cluster-scoped.

Answer (score 2):

In case you are wanting to wait for a resource that may not exist yet, you can try something like this:

```
{ grep -q -m 1 "crontabs.stable.example.com"; kill $!; } < <(kubectl get crd -w)
```

or

```
{ sed -n /crontabs.stable.example.com/q; kill $!; } < <(kubectl get crd -w)
```

I understand the question would prefer to only use `kubectl`, however this answer helped in my case. The downside to this method is that the timeout will have to be set in a different way and that the condition itself is not actually checked.

In order to check the condition more thoroughly, I made the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

condition-established() {
    local name="crontabs.stable.example.com"
    local condition="Established"

    jq --arg NAME $name --arg CONDITION $condition -n \
        'first(inputs | if (.metadata.name==$NAME) and (.status.conditions[]?.type==$CONDITION) then
            null | halt_error else empty end)' 

    # This is similar to the first, but the full condition is sent to stdout
    #jq --arg NAME $name --arg CONDITION $condition -n \
    #    'first(inputs | if (.metadata.name==$NAME) and (.status.conditions[]?.type==$CONDITION) then
    #        .status.conditions[] | select(.type==$CONDITION) else empty end)' 
}

{ condition-established; kill $!; } < <(kubectl get crd -w -o json)

echo Complete
```

To explain what is happening, `$!` refers to the command run by bash's process substitution. I'm not sure how well this might work in other shells.

I tested with the [CRD](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/extend-kubernetes/custom-resources/custom-resource-definitions/) from the official kubernetes documentation.